# JavaScript: Array of Images

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning HTML and JavaScript and to start off, I'm creating a simple website that displays 4 images using a for loop. However, when I view in Browser, I can only see the names of the images, but not the images themselves. Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<div id = "products" align = "center">

 <script>

  function showImages() {
    var productImg = new Array("a.png", "b.png", "c.png","d.png");
    var x = " ";

     for (var i = 0; i < productImg.length; i++) {

        var image = productImg[i];
        x += image;

    }

    var getImg = document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = x;
}



  </script>
  </div>
  <body onload = "showImages()">

   </body>
   </html>
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Your images need img tag :) And for the question what are you missing I have to answer almost everything in HTML.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <script>
        function showImages() {
            var productImg = ["a.png", "b.png", "c.png","d.png"];
            var x = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < productImg.length; i++) {
                var image = productImg[i];
                x += '<img src="' + image + '"/>';
            }
            var getImg = document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = x;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="showImages()">
    <div id="products" align="center"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or you could declare img tags in productImg array. That way you could add width and height and other attributes to img tags

Answer (score 0):

Joni's answer is pretty much right - but while you are learning, just keep in mind that HTML is "just" a structured text document, and that will get you a long way. Once you are ready to create content dynamically, then be prepared for a lot of learning with the DOM.. But, it seems like you already know some code, so that's half the battle. ;)

To give you an idea of how you can do this with JS, what you are looking for is the `Image` object. You create a new Image by writing something like.. `var myPicture = new Image();`. As it stands, this does not yet exist in your document, and it does not have a source - a path to a resource, but you do have a reference to your new image, which you can do things with.

You give it a source by changing its `src` attribute, like this: `myPicture.src="a.png";`. However, you have to keep in mind (and this counts for many, many things) that the operation of loading that image is **asynchronous**. That means that if you were to add the image to the document, you won't see anything until the image is loaded. Images are a good place to start on understanding this. Try playing around with these commands in your console (developer tools in chrome) and see what difference it makes.

```
var myPicture = new Image();
myPicture.src = 'a.png';
document.body.appendChild(myPicture); // may or may not show the image, depending on how long it takes to load, but should be almost instant on a localhost or file

var myEmptyPicture = new Image();
document.body.appendChild(myEmptyPicture); // you will see the empty image tag in the document
myEmptyPicture.onload = function(){
  console.log('I have finished loading the picture!')
};
myEmptyPicture.src = 'b.png'; // you kept the reference to the image, so you can change its src attribute even while it is in the document - this is important for more advanced stuff, and it should log a message to your console

// last one, this will insert itself into the document once it has loaded
myAutomaticPicture = new Image();
myAutomaticPicture.onload = function(){
  console.log('picture loaded, inserting into document');
  document.body.appendChild(myAutomaticPicture); // should see it in the document now
}
myAutomaticPicture.src = 'c.png';
```

The onload attribute is special in that it takes a function as its value. This function is called when the image has finished loading.

Things to try, changing src attributes on elements you already have in the DOM, or making other elements with the document.createElement method and appending them (eg: `var heading = document.createElement('h1'); heading.innerHTML='hello'; document.appendChild(heading);` ).

It's quite fun once you start seeing how all this fits together...

Comment: danp, Thank you for your help! I will definitely take this into consideration for future projects. Thanks!